# What happens technically when I export function A which calls func B and C, without exporting B and C explicitely?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Im currently fiddling around with ZURB foundation 6.4 framework which runs on Gulp, Babel7 and Webpack 4. 
Im experimenting with the ES6 export/import feature.

Now I have the following JS which exports the following code, and then the JS which imports it:

```
//JS exporting
 function consoletest(){
  console.log("HelloRequire!")
}

 function commonAJAXCall(){
  return $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {

      }).then((response) => {
        response = JSON.stringify(response)
        console.log(response)
        console.log("AJAX happened")
        return response
  })
}

 export async function productnamesGetter(){
  let productNameElements = document.getElementsByClassName('customProductCardName')
  await commonAJAXCall()
  console.log("result is ", productNameElements)
}


//JS importing

import * as myModule from './lib/eCommerceLogic.js'
$("#AJAXproductnames").on("click",  function(){

   myModule.productnamesGetter()

})
```

Now I already tried out what happens if I try to call function B or C: I get an error that its undefined.

Thats totaly fine, I think this is awesome!
But I would be really interested how this actually is done on the techside of ES6. How does it make the functions B and C accessible for the calling function A, but still inaccessible to explicit calls not "nested" inside the exported function A?

Comment: Where are you trying to call B or C that produces an error? Calling `commonAJAXCall` from `productnamesGetter` does work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

With closures.

Code in module gets executed when it is imported. So, we can represent it with this IIFE:

```js
const imported = (()=>{
  "use strict";
  //module code
  return exported;
})();
```

Ok, it isn't done *exactly* like this, but similarly.

So, you can imagine it like this:

```js
const foo = (()=>{
  "use strict";
  const foo = ()=>{
    console.log('foo called');
    bar()
  };
  const bar = ()=>{
    console.log('bar called')
  };
  return foo;
})();

foo(); //foo called, bar called
bar(); //ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

`foo` will receive a so-called closure, which is a set of variables (in this case, functions) which is inherited from where the function was defined, not where is called.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding I can consider es6 modules as an approximate case of the the famous *"module pattern"*.

Consider the example below where the ***IIFE*** comprising of the function `outer` is encapsulation two functions one is a function called `-inner` and the other is called `exported`, while I am only returning the `exported` function. Here I have called the `_inner` inside the exported function.

Although I get a reference of the `exported` function after executing the IIFE, the reference to the `_inner` is still there because of the closure which formed when I declared the `exported` function. The `outer` call happened and returned but the `exported` still has a reference to the `_inner` through the closure.

```js
const exported = (function outer(){

  function _inner(){
    console.log("inner");
  }
  
  function exported(){
    _inner();
    console.log("from exported");
  }
  
  return exported;

})();


exported();
```

I believe the same happens in the case of es6 modules, modules have their own scope which kind of acts like the closure in my example where the public exported functions can refer the module scope (which they retain access to) and call functions which are local to the module.